# Error in inserting new android activity

Tags: android

In my application I inserted new activity call "Cool". for this java class, layout XML file and menu XML file populated. but in on_create method its showing error like

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentCiew(R.layout.activity_cool);`
```

(under activity_cool)

error is :activity_cool is cannot be resolved or is not a field 
I checked in r.java class. but in layout method "cool"property is not created and also in menu method. i tried to insert new property with "cool" but i don't know how assign value for it. if anybody knows please reply me quickly. thanks buddies.

Comment: post `activity_coll.xml` and the import statements

Comment: have you mentioned this activity in manifiest

Comment: it's not setContentCiew. It's setContentView. check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following line of your `onCreate()` method...

```
setContentCiew(R.layout.activity_cool);
```

with this line...

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_cool);
```